# pygame mixer not playing sound when window is not active

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

Pygame mixer doesn't play audio when the Pygame window is not active. Is it possible to program it in such was that even in background it load and play new sound file?
below is my code for pygame.

```
from pygame import mixer
def playSound(file):
    mixer.quit()
    mixer.init(26000)
    file_path = "Sound/" + file + ".mp3"
    my_file = os.path.isfile(file_path)
    mixer.music.load(file_path)
    mixer.music.play()
    while mixer.music.get_busy():
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that you are using python 2.7 and not 3.5, When i run this code i get sound even if the window is not active. Updating brings alot of other benefits so i would absolutely recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I cannot move to 3.5 due to some library dependency issues. Some of the libraries I am using only supported in Python 2.7